# Where do methyl groups in the human body come from?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

Where do methyl groups in the human body or other mammals come from? Do we synthesize them (where?) Do we get them from our diets (in what? anything beside methionine?) Do our gut microbes produce them for us (and are we dependent on them for that?)

Comment: Well, as it's Christmas, I'll play Santa and give you some *S*-adenosylmethionine for your biochemistry Lego set. You'll need to consult the [instruction page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22459/#A3361) to see how to use it and what other pieces are needed. Another time you may find the [biochemistry manual](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/) useful for the [research you are expected to do before posting](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am new here and did not see instructions about what I was supposed to do before posting a question.  Regarding the question itself: the methionine-homocysteine cycle does not CREATE methyl groups--it only passes them around and activates/deactivates them.  I am trying to find out where they are synthesized, whether we have endogenous production of them or are reliant on exogenous sources, and if so, what are those sources. (I find it hard to believe that we can get enough solely from ingestion of methionine.)  Anyone else?  Thanks.

Comment: Read the whole section. The methyl group for the cycle comes from methylene tetrahydrofolate, which is produced by the reaction of serine with tetrahydrofolate. And serine, as you should know from your studies of the central metabolic pathways, is not an essential amino acid, but is synthesized from an intermediate of glycolysis. You wouldn't be thinking that methylation only happens to the amino acid residues of histones, or that you can understand its bichemistry without actually studying basic biochemistry, would you?